# Return a body with a REST DELETE

Tags: rest, http

I am implementing a REST api for setting and retrieving a resource.

My initial implementation was pretty straightforward:

1) PUT - path specifies {id} on which to store, request body is a JSON object to store, returns a 200 response when successful

2) GET - path specifies {id} on which to retrieve, request body is empty, returns a 200 response and the stored JSON object in the body

3) DELETE - path specifies {id} to delete, request body is empty, returns a 200 and an empty body (yes, probably should be a 204)

However, an upstream party with more clout than me is requesting that we do a destructive retrieval of the JSON object. They are adamant that they don't want the bother of making separate GET and DELETE calls (i.e., it really has nothing to do with someone trying to ensure an atomic call to eliminate race conditions).

To me this seems to violate the spirit of a RESTful service, and when I attempt to document this change the API documentation has a definite "code smell" in that it just feels awkward when attempting to clearly document a GET/DELETE method.

Obviously I can implement whatever works, but is there a well-established convention on a destructive read? Surely there are cases where there is a genuine need for an atomic call?

Comment: No sure I understand your question. Did you mean to send the JSON as a DELETE response or delete the object in a GET request?

Comment: How is question different from your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173786/return-a-modified-object-in-a-rest-put ?

Answer (score 3):

What they're asking for has nothing to do with REST, but it is contrary to the HTTP RFC (#7231).

> If a DELETE method is successfully applied, the origin server
>   SHOULD send a 202 (Accepted) status code if the action will likely
>   succeed but has not yet been enacted, a 204 (No Content) status
>   code if the action has been enacted and no further information is
>   to be supplied, or a 200 (OK) status code if the action has been
>   enacted and the response message includes a representation
>   describing the status.

That's pretty clear. You can return a `200 (Ok)`, but the entity in the response should be a status object, not the deleted object. Of course, you may be bullied into doing this anyway, office politics being what they are. Ask them for a proven technical reason for why you need to violate the RFC. Don't accept handwavey "it's too expensive" claims - make them provide actual test cases that prove there's an issue.

There are no defined semantics that I'm aware of for an atomic read/delete operation. It would be difficult to advise you on how to proceed without a lot more information, which is probably out of scope for this site.